# AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute when I try to get values out of a table

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup, python-requests

I try to scrape a website and get values out of a table using Python.
This goes well until I want to grap the value only (so without the html).

I try to get the value out of the field by using the following code:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from urllib.request import Request, urlopen
import requests

req = Request('https://www.formula1.com/en/results.html/2022/drivers.html', headers={'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0'})
webpage = urlopen(req).read()


soup = BeautifulSoup(webpage,'html.parser')


drivers = soup.find('table',class_='resultsarchive-table').find_all('tr')

for driver in drivers:
    rank = driver.find('td', class_='dark')
    first = driver.find('span',class_='hide-for-tablet')
    last = driver.find('span',class_='hide-for-mobile')
    print (rank)
```

When I use .text or .get_text() I get the error AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute  while the code above contains values.

What do I do incorrect?

Comment: You need to include the part of your code where you are trying to run `.text` or `.get_text()`, as well as the full stacktrace that goes with the error message. Right now it's not clear where the error comes from.

Comment: I did it like in the answer: rank = driver.find('td', class_='dark').text

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Issu here is that you also grab the row with table headers that do not contain any `<td>`. But you can simply slice them:

```
for driver in drivers[1:]:
    rank = driver.find('td', class_='dark').text
    first = driver.find('span',class_='hide-for-tablet').text
    last = driver.find('span',class_='hide-for-mobile').text
    print (rank)
```

or select more specific for example with `css selectors`:

```
drivers = soup.select('table.resultsarchive-table tr:has(td)')

for driver in drivers:
    rank = driver.find('td', class_='dark').text
    first = driver.find('span',class_='hide-for-tablet').text
    last = driver.find('span',class_='hide-for-mobile').text
    print (rank)
```